# Parsing wikipedia stubs using python wikitools

Tags: python, api, parsing, mediawiki

I implemented the example from: [Mediawiki and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589873/wikitools-wikipedia-and-python/6593085#6593085)

I read [Get wikipedia abstract using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429597/get-wikipedia-abstract-using-python/8431544#8431544) and [How to parse/extract data from a mediawiki marked-up article via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968132/how-to-parse-extract-data-from-a-mediawiki-marked-up-article-via-python) and several others.

I am trying to get a dump of some Wikipedia stubs associated with a category and insert them into an internal semantic mediawiki site.  For the purpose of this example I am using the "Somali_Region" category. The script uses the mediawiki API to obtain data then it parses the data removing all template information which is desirable.

```
from wikitools import wiki
from wikitools import category
import mwparserfromhell

wikisite = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
parse_category = "Somali_Region"

wikiObject = wiki.Wiki(wikisite) 
wikiCategory = category.Category(wikiObject, parse_category)
articles = wikiCategory.getAllMembersGen(namespaces=[0])

for article in articles:
   wikiraw = article.getWikiText()
   parsedWikiText = mwparserfromhell.parse(wikiraw)
   for template in parsedWikiText.filter_templates():
      parsedWikiText.remove(template)
   print parsedWikiText
```

The internal semantic mediawiki site fails if I try to do a dump from wikipedia and do an insert, so that is not an option.  Is it possible to do use the API to insert data into the semantic mediawiki site?  I read the [mediawiki API edit page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit_-_Create%26Edit_pages), but I could not find a python example.

Comment: Have you tried `pywikipediabot`? I haven't tried `wikitools` yet, it looks good and I'll probably try it out soon. I have good experiences with `pywikipediabot`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to take your `parsedWikiText` and save it into a private wiki.

Here's what I have for doing that kind of thing (you'll need to store `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` somewhere; I use a config file, but there are more secure ways). I'll pick up from right before your `for` loop...

```
# Set up and authenticate into the target wiki if you need to.
from wikitools import wiki, page
target_wiki = wiki.Wiki('http://wiki.example.com/w/api.php')
site.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

for article in articles:
    wikiraw = article.getWikiText()
    parsedWikiText = mwparserfromhell.parse(wikiraw)
    for template in parsedWikiText.filter_templates():
        parsedWikiText.remove(template)

    # Use the API's edit function to save the new content.
    target_title = article.title
    target_page = page.Page(target_wiki, target_title)
    result = target_page.edit(text=parsedWikiText, summary="Imported text")

    # Check to see if it worked.
    if result['edit']['result'] == 'Success':
        print 'Saved', target_title
    else:
        print 'Save failed', target_title
```

I'm assuming here you want to save `parsedWikiText` into a new page. If there's already something on the page in your wiki, you'll have to read it first with `target_page.getWikiText()` and then mix the new text in somehow. I've also assumed the article will have the same name it had in Wikipedia; if not then change `target_title`.